# Plotting an InterpolatingFunction outside its domain doesn't raise error messages

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, interpolation

Let's make an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
if = Interpolation[Transpose[{#, Sin@#} &@Range[0, 4, 0.1]]];
```

As expected, evaluating it outside of its domain switches from interpolation to extrapolation, giving a pretty wacky result. However, Mathematica helpfully warns you about this

```
if[10]
(* InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {10} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. 

36.3612 *)
```

However, when I go and `Plot` it, no such warning is offered:

```
Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: if blowing right the heck up]

This is in Mathematica 12.0+. I have a strong recollection that I used to get warnings when I tried to plot `InterpolatingFunction`s outside their domain, and if at all possible I would really like to have that behavior back.

Comment: You could flag it using `ColorFunction`, e.g., `Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 10}, ColorFunction -> Function[{t, f}, If[t > if[[1, 1, -1]], Red, ColorData[97][1]]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`

Comment: For better or for worse, `Plot[]` does suppress error messages. Consider the following: `test[t_] := If[TrueQ[Between[t, if["Domain"]]], if[t], Message[InterpolatingFunction::dmval, t]; Undefined]; Plot[test[t], {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: You could instead use: `if = Interpolation[Transpose[{#, Sin@#} &@Range[0, 4, 0.1]], "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]` so that extrapolation is not used.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to override the `Quiet` run of the command Plot. However, you can intercept the messages and store them in a list to be browsed afterwards.

For example,

```
errorlst = {};
Plot[if[t], {t, 0, 10},
 EvaluationMonitor :> 
  If[Length[$MessageList] > 0, 
   AppendTo[errorlst, {$MessageList[[-1]], t}]]
 ]
```

To get the error messages later on, do:

```
Map[Message[# // Sequence] &, errorlst];
```